# How to force navigationservice.navigateto reuse the existing instance of activity or viewcontroller

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am using the sameview controller in multiple places but I intend  to reuse the same instance if viewcontrollee everywhere that i use

How can I customize navigationservice's navigateto to make this happen ?

As far as I know if the instance is of singleton then its possible ?

But how to customize ?